# etTodoTitle.text not being accessed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

when the app is ran the Edit Text's text is not being accessed and passed for some reason instead this is what it shows in the recycler view and my room database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg0TM.jpg

Sorry if this question doesn't make much sense I didn't really know how to phrase it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Activity Main**

```
package com.example.todoit

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import com.example.todoit.data.TodoDataBase
import com.example.todoit.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var todoDB: TodoDataBase
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        todoDB = TodoDataBase.getInstance(this)
        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())

        val rvTodoItems = binding.rvTodoItems
        val btnAddTodo = binding.btnAddTodo
        val btnDeleteTodo = binding.btnDeleteTodo

        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter

        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
            val todoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle.toString()

            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = Todo(null, todoTitle, false)

                GlobalScope.launch {
                    todoDB.todoDao().insertAll(todo)
                }

                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)

                binding.etTodoTitle.text.clear()

                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully written data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error while writing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }


        btnDeleteTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Todo(s) Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

**TodoAdapter**

```
package com.example.todoit

import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_todo.view.*


class TodoAdapter(
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>,
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    }

    fun addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size - 1)
    }

    fun deleteDoneTodos() {
        todos.removeAll { todo ->
            todo.isChecked
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if(isChecked) {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
            cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
            cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

**Gradle(app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "kotlin-android-extensions"
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.todoit"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}



dependencies {
    //ROOM
    def roomVersion = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5"
}
```

If you need anymore code then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to change the following assignment:

```
val todoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle.toString()
```

to this:

```
val todoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle.text.toString()
```

Otherwise any new Todo objects created by the onClick will store the View ID of the editText instead of the value you typed inside it...